# element.currentSrc returns URL in every browser except Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, firefox

I am trying to get the URL of a responsive image loaded via the srcset HTML property.

I have so far managed this by requesting the currentSrc of the image along the lines of the code below.

```
<img ID="image1" src="http://www.example.com/123.jpg" srcset="http://www.example.com/123.jpg 480w, http://www.example.com/123-large.jpg 640w,">

<script>
    var $currImg = $('#image1');
    var img = $currImg.get(0); //retrieve DOM element from $currImg
    console.log(img.currentSrc);
</script>
```

In most browsers, this logs the URL, for example, "http://www.example.com/123-large.jpg".

However in Firefox, it logs a data URI along the lines of:

"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="

This data URI does not seem to work for my intended purpose. I am trying to set the src as the background-image for another element. It just seems to load an empty image in Firefox.

Why is Firefox converting the URL to a data URI and is there any way to force it to return a normal URL?

Answer (score 1):

This dataURL is a 1px by 1px image, probably one that the browser does set when the img is loading the next image. I personaly don't have it on my FF63 on osX, and I would suspect it is a bug that you can access it from scripts... (or could some extension have set it?).

But anyway, what you need to do, is to wait for the `onload` event, so that the `currentSrc` is effectively resolved.

```js
console.log('before load', image1.currentSrc);
image1.onload = function() {
  console.log('after load', image1.currentSrc);
};
```

```html
<img id="image1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg/619px-John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg" srcset="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg/100px-John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg 100w, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg/330px-John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg 330w">
```

Comment: Huh, that makes it much more difficult. As I indicated what I'm actually doing is a bit more complicated than I let on. I'm hooking into the afterload() callback of lazy.js (http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_callback-functions). So this shouldn't even be running until the image has confirmed to be loaded. My Javascript strength is only so-so. Can you think of anything I could add to this to make it wait/check if the image has loaded?

Comment: `$('.srcSet').lazy({
    afterLoad: function(element) { 
        var $currImg = element;
        var img = $currImg.get(0);
        console.log(img.currentSrc);
        var src = img.currentSrc ? img.currentSrc : img.src;
        $currImg.closest('.js-bgFromSrcSetLazy').css('background-image', "url('"+src+"')").addClass('js-lazy-loaded');
        element.remove();
    },
  });`

Comment: Hum I don't know this plugin, but I don't see how a lazy load plugin can work with srcset. I think your plugin will try to load the image pointed by the `data-src` attribute. In your markup there is no such attribute. Why do you think you need this lazy-load plugin?

Comment: It certainly does work with SRC Set. I am not sure how to share my full markup neatly here, but it does work and it is extremely fast. Essentially it loads the image and copies the currentSrc at the appropriate size for the screen. It then applies that SRC as the background image for the container and then deletes the original image. Pages load super fast due to the combination of lazy loading and using srcset to load the correct background image resolution. My only problem is that in Firefox, currentSrc returns the data-URI.